# Check if string only contains alphanumeric and dot characters

Tags: php, regex, validation, alphanumeric, whitelist

I need to check to see if a variable contains anything OTHER than `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9` and the `.` character (full stop).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
if (preg_match('/[^A-Z\d.]/i', $var))
  print $var;
```

Answer (score 10):

There are two ways of doing it.

Tell whether the variable contains any one character *not* in the allowed ranges. This is achieved by using a negative character class [^...]:

```
preg_match('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\.]/', $your_variable);
```

Th other alternative is to make sure that every character in the string *is* in the allowed range:

```
!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9\.]*$/', $your_variable);
```

Answer (score 8):

```
if (preg_match("/[^A-Za-z0-9.]/", $myVar)) {
   // make something
}
```

The key point here is to use "^" in the [] group - it matches every character except the ones inside brackets.

Comment: I think that this would only detect strings consisting of _only_ the unspecified characters - it might be better to use /[^A-Za-z0-9\.]/

Comment: Much better. But I still suggest /[^A-Z\d.]/i since it's clearer and less to type. And you don't need to escape the "." inside character classes.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to wheel out the regex engine, you can ltrim the string by the whitelisted characters, then check if the string is empty.

Yes, the `trim()` functions allow character ranges to be expressed via "yatta-yatta" dots.  Read more about it at [Native PHP functions that allow double-dot range syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72865138/2943403).

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/rRpY2))

```
if (ltrim($str, 'A..Za..z0..9.') !== '') {
    // all good
}
```