# PHP Only allow certain characters and replace all others

Tags: php

I have a PHP Variable which i need to remove all special characters from, like `% / é / !` etc

how can i replace all characters OTHER than `A-Z` / `a-z` / `0-9` and `.` (full stop) with a `_`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Allowing Only Certain Characters In PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396166/allowing-only-certain-characters-in-php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this ought to work.

```
preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9\.]/", "_", $str);
```

Comment: Needs `0-9` inside the `[]`.

Comment: this doesn't seem to be doing letters like é or anything

Comment: I believe `[^\w.]` would be an equivalent abbreviation. (`\w` includes `_` too, but replacing `_` with `_` is effectively nothing. If replacing with something other than `_`, then `\w` would not be correct.)

Comment: I would not assume that `\w` would exclude alphabetic but non-ASCII characters like `é`. Won't that depend on your locale?

Comment: @qwrrty PCRE will only match ASCII alphabet unless Unicode is explicitly enabled. Some other regex engines act differently, however, so you make a good point.